# Javascript rounding this number down 9703248444284653

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this has something to do with floating point math or something, but I need to out how to correctly interpret this number 9703248444284653. Javascript apparently doesn't like it

If I just do this.

```
var test = 9703248444284653
console.log(test)
```

The result is 9703248444284652, which is obviously not correct. Problem is that 9703248444284653 is an id that can't be changed. I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: Hint: `console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)`

Answer (score 0):

Your value is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

```js
console.log(9703248444284653n > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

You should treat your IDs as [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) values. So you can should probably store the values as strings and then parse them as `BigInt` values if you need to perform any math on them.

```js
const
  bigIntNative = 9703248444284653n,
  bigIntConstructed = BigInt('9703248444284653');

console.log(typeof bigIntNative === 'bigint' && bigIntNative === bigIntConstructed);

console.log(`${bigIntNative}`);
```